# Pyspark Array Key,Value

Tags: multidimensional-array, key-value, pyspark

I currently have an RDD with an array that stores a key-value pair where the key is the 2D indices of the array and the value is the number at that spot. For example [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((1,0),3),((1,1),4)]
I want to add up the values of each key with the surrounding values. In relation to my earlier example, I want to add up 1,2,3 and place it in the (0,0) key value spot. How would I do this?

Comment: I can't figure out what you want. Normally in python you should use a map for any key-value pair, why do you use arrays - where one can hardly figure out the exact meaning of the stored tupples.

Comment: Can you make it clearer? If you write the output that you want from that given array and explain it I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do the following:

1. Define a function that, given a pair (i,j), returns a list with the pairs corresponding to the positions surrounding (i,j), plus the input pair (i,j). For instance, lets say the function is called `surrounding_pairs(pair)`. Then:

   ```
   surrounding_pairs((0,0)) = [ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) ]
   surrounding_pairs((2,3)) = [ (2,3), (2,2), (2,4), (1,3), (3,3) ]
   ```

   Of course, you need to be careful and return only valid positions.
2. Use a `flatMap` on your RDD as follows:

   ```
   MyRDD = MyRDD.flatMap(lambda (pos, v): [(p, v) for p in surrounding_pairs(pos)])
   ```

   This will map your RDD from
   `[((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((1,0),3),((1,1),4)]` to

   ```
   [((0,0),1),((0,1),1),((1,0),1),
    ((0,1),2),((0,0),2),((1,1),2),
    ((1,0),3),((0,0),3),((1,1),3),
    ((1,1),4),((1,0),4),((0,1),4)]
   ```

   This way, the value at each position will be "copied" to the neighbour positions.
3. Finally, just use a `reduceByKey` to add the corresponding values at each position:

   ```
   from operator import add
   MyRDD = MyRDD.reduceByKey(add)
   ```

I hope this makes sense.